# Comparing words in two textbox to find difference?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, compare

I have 2 TextBoxes.

I want to compare all the words of Textbox1 with Textbox2

Let say if the second word in Textbox1 is "me" while second word in Textbox 2 is "him" it will highlight the word "him" on Textbox 2 and "me" on Textbox1.

Example :

Box 1 = i am a **boy**

box 2 = i am a **girl**

Box 1 = **he** is a **boy**

box 2 =**she** is a **girl**

but now i having a problem with compare the words. i try to do compare by array index but it will only show the words that not found in Textbox1 !

```
    Dim txt1(TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    Dim txt2(TextBox2.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    txt1 = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    txt2 = TextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim diff1 As String = "" 'Differences between 1 and 2
    Dim diff2 As String = "" 'Differences between 2 and 1

    For Each diff As String In txt1
        If Array.IndexOf(txt2, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff1 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
    For Each diff As String In txt2
        If Array.IndexOf(txt1, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
            diff2 += diff.ToString & " "
        End If
    Next
```

and i also face a problem which is cannot highlight the text

Comment: Your code worked for me, check it (and arrays values) executing step by step

Comment: If you want some words (but not all) in bold text, use RichTextBox control instead of TextBox.

Comment: @Blackwood my web project only got textbox in toolbox , dont have richtextbox..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Linq [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) extension:

```
Dim diffs = txt1.Except(txt2)
```

Output:

> - diffs(0) = "he"
> - diffs(1) = "boy"

And you can swap between txt1 with txt2:

```
Dim diffs = txt2.Except(txt1)
```

Output:

> - diffs(0) = "she"
> - diffs(1) = "girl"

Comment: Thx..it give me idea about how to do...
the way i do is 
` For i = 0 To txt2.Length - 1
   If txt2(i) <> txt1(i) Then
   diff1 += txt1(i).ToString & "  "
   End If
   Next i `

Answer (score 0):

Can use this way also

```
    Dim txt1(TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    Dim txt2(TextBox2.Text.Split(" ").Length) As String
    txt1 = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    txt2 = TextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim diff1 As String = "" 'Differences between 1 and 2
    Dim diff2 As String = "" 'Differences between 2 and 1

    For i = 0 To txt2.Length - 1
        If txt2(i) <> txt1(i) Then
            diff1 += txt1(i).ToString & "  "

        End If

    Next i

    For x = 0 To txt1.Length - 1
        If txt1(x) <> txt2(x) Then
            diff2 += txt2(x).ToString & "  "
        End If

    Next x
```